# Sum variable by group and append result

Tags: r, append, data-cleaning

Dataset `HAVE` is a tibble edgelist of phone call data from the characters of *Recess*:

```
Student   Friend       nCalls
TJ        Spinelli          3
TJ        Gretchen          7
TJ        Gus               6
TJ        Vince             8
TJ        King Bob          1
TJ        Mikey             2
Spinelli  TJ                3
Spinelli  Vince             2
Randall   Ms. Finster      17
```

Dataset `NEED` includes all original columns from `HAVE` but includes a new variable, `nCallsPerStudent`, that is exactly what it sounds like:

```
Student   Friend       nCalls   nCallsPerStudent
TJ        Spinelli          3                 27
TJ        Gretchen          7                 27
TJ        Gus               6                 27
TJ        Vince             8                 27
TJ        King Bob          1                 27
TJ        Mikey             2                 27
Spinelli  TJ                3                  5
Spinelli  Vince             2                  5
Randall   Ms. Finster      17                 17
```

How do I get from `HAVE` to `NEED`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'student' and `mutate` to create the new column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  mutate(nCallsPerStudent = sum(nCalls))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$nCallsPerStudent <- with(df, ave(nCalls, Student, FUN = sum))
```

Comment: Doing this (your dplyr answer) does not produce `NEED` - it sums the entirety of `nCalls` independent of the `group_by()` condition, so every line in `nCallsPerStudent` = 49. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JMQ  You may have loaded `plyr` library where there is `mutate` that masks the `dplyr` mutate.  One option is to explicitly use `group_by(Student) %>% dplyr::mutate(nCallsPerStudent = sum(nCalls))`

Comment: @lefft why is this?

Comment: bc otherwise you will have a grouped data frame, and every subsequent operation will be applied to each group of the df (here, students) instead of the df as a whole. try `%>% mutate(maxcalls = max(nCalls))` next, with and without doing `%>% ungroup() %>%` first and you'll see what i mean :p